# yarn set registry failed, how to reset it?

Tags: yarnpkg

I want to set registry to "https://registry.npm.taobao.org", but it seems failed.
How to set the registry to the default value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldta2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem just now. You can set yarn registry in the `.yarnrc` file located in `C:\Users\yours` folder. This is truly a bug.